# React D3 line chart Tooltips missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts

Below is the code we use for displaying line chart. However, we are not seeing the Tool-tips enabled. Any suggestions on what to look for? Sorry new to react framework. Similar code for Area chart works fine with tool-tips.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import D3Chart from '../area/D3Chart';
import DataUtils from '../../utils/DataUtils';

export default class LineChart extends Component {
     xTicksFormat(d) {
         if (this.props.xMappingData) {
             let retVal =  DataUtils.findMapping(this.props.xMappingData, d-1);
             if (retVal)
                 return retVal;
             else
                 return '';
         }
         else if (this.props.xMappingData2) {
             let retVal = DataUtils.findMapping2(this.props.xMappingData2, d);
             if (retVal)
                 return retVal;
         }
         else
             return d;
     }

    yTicksFormat(d) {
        return d;
    }

    render(){
        var data= this.props.data;
        var margin={
            top: 50, right: 30, bottom: 50, left: 50
        };

        return(
            <div className="row  outerbox bigChart">
                <div className="col-md-12 custom_padding" >
                        <D3Chart data={data} xData="x" yData="y" margin={margin} interpolations="basis" xMaxBuffer={-30}
                                         yMaxBuffer={20} id="line-chart" width={480} height={400} type="line">
                            <yGrid orient="left" className="y-grid" ticks={12} title={data.yTitle} ticksFormat={this.yTicksFormat.bind(this)}/>
                            <xGrid orient="bottom" className="x-grid" ticks={5} title={data.xTitle} ticksFormat={this.xTicksFormat.bind(this)}/>
                            <line />
                            <path className="line shadow" strokeLinecap="round"/>

                            <tooltip textStyle1="tooltip-text1"
                                textStyle2="tooltip-text1" bgStyle="tooltip-bg"
                                xValue="Date" yValue="Count"/>
                            {/*<axisTitle text={data.xTitle} axisType='x' />
                            <axisTitle text={data.yTitle} axisType='y'/> */}
                        </D3Chart>
                </div>
                <span className="chartPadding"></span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```